# Reliable virtual serial communication (STM32)

Tags: serial-port, stm32, mbed

I have a `NUCLEO-F746ZG` board connected to my PC through the ST-Link USB connection. The PC sends different commands to the microcontroller and the microcontroller sends a stream of data (~15 KByte/s) back to the PC. In addition to that the controller board communicates with another device over ethernet and there are some timer interrupts which change the state of output pins etc.

Now the problem I have is that sometimes a byte is completly lost during transmission from PC to controller. The controller is programmed using [MBed](https://www.mbed.com/en/) and uses BufferedSerial (uses serial interrupts to fill an internal buffer). The size of the BufferedSerial connection should be more than big enough to hold the data until it is processed. And the baud rate is currently set to 500000 - So should also be fine.

I thought that I can expect a reliable connection to the controller board because it is only a virtual serial port over USB. Is this assumption incorrect and I have to implement a reliable protocol on top of it? If it should just work - Does anyone have an idea what the issue might be?

Comment: For the reliable implement the CDC class using your micro. Forget about the stlink ine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to enable hardware flow control on the UART instance. You can do this via the [__HAL_UART_HWCONTROL_CTS_ENABLE](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/blob/5648b156e6dd95c46114f6a1239e70e1991b7855/targets/TARGET_STM/TARGET_STM32F7/device/stm32f7xx_hal_uart.h#L883) macro on your platform.

**edit:** There seems to actually be [hardware flow control](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/blob/9ddb092d4359517797999d28def84a81fa725ced/drivers/SerialBase.cpp#L147) supported in the Mbed OS library. Not sure if it's implemented on the F746ZG, but worth a try.

Comment: Can't test it right now but i guess this solves the problem